# Is celery concurrency count is equal to number of tasks that can execute at once?

Tags: python, redis, queue, celery

I understand that you should essentially set your worker count to the number of cores your node has, and if you go beyond that, you'll probably overwhelm the node.

I have hundreds of web requests (each as their own task) that will need to every minute, currently routing all of these through `apply_async()`.

If I set my concurrency `-c 10`, does that mean it can only execute up to 10 of those requests at a time? Or is the concurrency count not necessarily equal to the amount of tasks it can execute at once?

It would be a waste of resources and wildly inefficient to only handle 10 requests at a time when most of that time is spent just waiting on the request to finish. When I find articles on mixing **asyncio** and **Celery**, people seem to think it's not a great idea. So what would be the solution here? Was Celery the wrong move, or does 10 concurrency ≠ only 10 simultaneous tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong approach. I should've gone with a thread-based approach using Celery: https://www.technoarchsoftwares.com/blog/optimization-using-celery-asynchronous-processing-in-django/

Switched to gevent and it's working exactly as I'd imagined now.